# Wordpress Network Host that Supports Subdomains

Tags: wordpress, hosting, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Pretty simple question that for some reason the people at WordPress.org seem unable to answer. I'm looking for a good/cheap host that will allow me to host a WordPress Network with subdomains. I'm not looking to build a huge site, I just want to write about two very different topics so SEO wise subdomains seem like the way to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I already explained that mods over there are not allowed to answer hosting questions in those forums. Elsewhere, we can. ;)

Hostgator works.

Comment: Haha, I got the hint, that's why I opened it here. Thanks again for the help Andrea_r. It's much appreciated. I'll check out Hostgator right now.